# Tradesman charging twice - call out the full cost of service

Tags: human-rights, property, consumer-protection

I bought a stove and called an Electrician to install it at my rental property.

> He quoted me $240+GST and I agreed and paid up front.

The Electrician called me back 30 minutes later saying the electrical socket in the stove had been tampered with and he couldn't install it. We agree he would come back and install it when I got the stove repaired / replaced.

> 3 weeks later the stovetop was replaced and my tenants got the tradesman back onsite. He called me in the morning to tell me it cost another $240! I told him "but I already paid" and we had a little chat and ended with "there will be a discount on this call out".

He rang me after installing the stove and said he called head office who wont budge on price. I told him it was exorbitant and amounted to $160 p/h and if I had pay they will not be happy at the online reviews they get from me. So he called head office again and called me back and said they would reduce it to $220 including GST. I think this is extortion, $484 all up for 3 hours time/labor. And I'd cut out the bench, fitted it and provided the heat resistant silicone. All he had to do was connect 3 wires +,- and earth and glue it in.

I am OK to pay a bit extra for the initial call out and a consulting fee incurred 1st time but not $220.

I'm NSW Australia, is there anything I can do? I haven't paid the additional charge yet and am speaking to the manager on Tuesday?

Advice much appreciated.

Comment: So you bought a stove that was defective?  Your job wasn't ready for him.  The electrician didn't do anything wrong and you consumed two slots (including drive time) of his capacity.

Comment: The call out fee is $45 and the service wasn't completed.

Comment: aha, unclear,  I thought the $240 was the price of the house call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your contract say?

That is, what *exactly* did your initial $240+GST pay for. If the quotation was for the installation of the stove without restrictions then you have already paid all that you are obliged to pay for. If there are limitations on the quotation then read and understand those.

When you agreed that he would come back; was there any mention of an additional charge?

When you speak to the manager, make them what you consider to be a reasonable offer as a full and final settlement. If they accept your offer, document that and pay them. If they don't then invite them to sue you and suggest the Local Court that would be most convenient for you to attend; let them convince a magistrate that you owe them more than you offered.

Comment: That's right there was no mention of any extra payment when we agreed he would come back.